# How can I increase performance calling to a web service from Windows 2008 Server?

Tags: web-services, tcp, windows-server-2008, packet

I'm trying to help out a co-worker here.  We are using the same code base however I'm running Win7 Ultimate and she Windows Server 2008. When I call a webservice, using the Stopwatch class, it's taking my call about 320ms, when she does the exact same call with the same payload etc... it's taking about 3,500ms. Any idea as to why this would be happening? This code is running an XQuery against an XML database...

```
 using (MarkLogicHttpReader reader = (MarkLogicHttpReader)cmd.ExecuteHttpReader())
 {
      var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      response.Xml.Value = reader.GetXml();
      watch.Stop();
      Debug.WriteLine("The call took : {0} ms", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
      response.Xml.HasData = HasData(response.Xml.Value);
  }
```

Any ideas how I can perhaps tweak her network settings or something to get the same throughput I'm getting. She's quite a good friend and I'd like to help her out if I can.  I was thinking maybe it's something to do with packet sizes or something? Anyways any ideas or tips are certainly appreciated. I know this is a programming forum and perhaps this is a networking question, but honestly we're both devs running the same piece of code. I'm just curious why it's so much slower on her machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a couple of things.

First, I would attempt to measure the time it takes for the `ExecuteHttpReader` call. It would be interesting to see how that varies between you and your colleague.

Second, I would look at the networking aspect. In particular, is there an Internet Proxy between you and the service? The proxy may be configured differently between a desktop machine and a server machine.

Finally, yes, use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to look at the network traffic in the slow case. See where the performance issue is.